# 1080p Rendering Problems 720p fine Though

Tags: rendering

I have downloaded a blender file for a YouTube intro. I can output the file to 1280x720 perfectly fine. For some reason though, when i change the dimensions to 1920x1080 but it puts BLACK BARS across the middle of the video.720p is perfectly fine though.[image]

Comment: Hi, can you indicate a link to the file you have downloaded ?

Comment: Looks like a stylistic effect somebody applied to the intro.  And it might have been an image that now doesn't look proper at the higher resolution.

Comment: Here is the link where I download the template: https://editorsdepot.com/video/free-clean-and-stiff-in-blue-blender-only-intro-template